# Why has my ubuntu connection dropped after switching providers?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I recently switched to Verizon. They installed a new modem at my house. I use a wifi usb device, the Asus N13. It has been working fine for me between ubuntu and Windows 7 with no problems for years. However with this switch, my connection with ubuntu is incredibly unstable. Sometimes it works, but at low speeds. A lot of times, it is connected to the modem but there is no internet connection. My windows 7 partition has not been impacted at all. Any ideas why? Can modems discriminate between OS?

Info:
Actiontec Model: WCB3000N
Ubuntu 15.04
wifi usb Asus N13

Comment: Can you provide the model number of the Verizon modem and the version of Ubuntu that you're running? Also describe some of the troubleshooting steps you've already taken (alternate wireless adapters, reinstalling the driver, etc).

Comment: Updated. I tried some other USB keys but I couldn't even get them to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Ubuntu on my laptop and it was working fine. I figured out what I did wrong as well. I came to rerun my script which installs my driver, I discovered that it was pulling from a no longer existent github. I must have not installed a decent driver and instead have been working on the default driver for chipset rt8192cu. So I found another github:

https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git

Still do not understand why it was working with stability before but this seems to have fixed the problem.